# How to show a non-interactive X session for displaying and periodically reload a webpage?

Tags: browser, webserver, xserver

I have I all-in-one-pc running a webserver. As its display is constantly on, I was wondering how I could use it to display a website in parallel, e.g. the webserver's status page https://localhost/my/status/page and refreshing it periodically.

As I don't want anyone to be able to use this browser window to browse the internet, it would need to be non-interactive, i.e. not reacting to mouse and keyboard. Is there such thing as a non-interactive X session in which I could start a browser?

It would be okay if someone could kill the session with a keystroke, I only want to prevent using the session for browsing or opening additional programs.

Comment: Why not turn off the screen? Eg. `sleep 1 ; xset dpms force off` [[source](https://superuser.com/questions/374637/how-to-turn-off-screen-with-shortcut-in-linux)]. Other than that it sounds like you're after "kiosk mode" which Opera browser used to do really well.

Comment: @pbhj The kiosk mode is a good hint, will take a look at it. Definitely a valid search word to find a suitable tool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## XInput

You can disable mouse and keyboard using libinput

In you session, open up a terminal and run

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So now you can disable the mouse, using the proper id:

```
xinput set-prop 6 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Don't use the **core** pointer, that will not work; so now you still see the cursor but its click does nothing.

You can disable the keyboard the same way

```
xinput set-prop 8 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Use 1 to enable them again

This is a manual method, you can turn this into a script autostarted with the session.

## xtrlock

Another solution is to use the little utility `xtrlock`

```
sudo apt install xtrlock
```

and then

```
xtrlock
```

Your mouse cursor will turn into a **lock** and typing  on the keyboard or clicking will do nothing. But if you type your password, the lock will be removed.
My test shows it does not work on 2 monitors, only one (in wayland) but this is not your setup it seems.